# Problem when trying to cross-compile an ethernet driver on an old Linux kernel

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, drivers, cross-compilation

I'm currently trying to cross-compile a network driver against an old Linux kernel, in version 2.6.27.7 but the compilation fails and prints:

```
make[1]: entering directory « /home/johann/Desktop/linux-2.6.27.7 »
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 0 modules
make[1]: leaving directory « /home/johann/Desktop/linux-2.6.27.7 »
```

The command I ran to get this was taken from the readme found with the sources:

```
make KSRC=<source> KDIR=<build>
```

Here's how it looks like:

```
#
# Makefile to build the be2net network driver
#

# find a source path that exists among the possible paths
ver = $(shell uname -r)
paths := /lib/modules/$(ver)/source /lib/modules/$(ver)/build
exists = $(shell [ -e $(path)/include/linux ] && echo $(path))
paths := $(foreach path, $(paths), $(exists))
ifeq (,$(KSRC))
    KSRC := $(firstword $(paths))
endif

# ************** Header checks ********************
ifneq (,$(shell grep -o alloc_etherdev_mqs $(KSRC)/include/linux/etherdevice.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DALLOC_ETHDEV_MQS_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o alloc_etherdev_mq $(KSRC)/include/linux/etherdevice.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DALLOC_ETHDEV_MQ_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o netif_set_real_num_rx_queues $(KSRC)/include/linux/netdevice.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DNETIF_SET_REAL_NUM_RX_QS_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o PCI_DEV_FLAGS_ASSIGNED $(KSRC)/include/linux/pci.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DPCI_FLAGS_ASSIGNED_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o skb_frag_set_page $(KSRC)/include/linux/skbuff.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DSKB_FRAG_API_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o skb_frag_size $(KSRC)/include/linux/skbuff.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DSKB_FRAG_SIZE_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o netdev_alloc_skb_ip_align $(KSRC)/include/linux/skbuff.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DALLOC_SKB_IP_ALIGN_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o skb_record_rx_queue $(KSRC)/include/linux/skbuff.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DSKB_RECORD_RX_QUEUE_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o rxhash $(KSRC)/include/linux/skbuff.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DRXHASH_defined
endif

#GRO is usable only when full implementation is available
ifneq (,$(shell grep -o napi_get_frags $(KSRC)/include/linux/netdevice.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DGRO_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o netdev_alloc_skb $(KSRC)/include/linux/skbuff.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DALLOC_SKB_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o dev_mc_list $(KSRC)/include/linux/netdevice.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DDEV_MC_LIST_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o pcie_set_readrq $(KSRC)/include/linux/pci.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DPCIE_SET_READRQ_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -so vlan_group_set_device $(KSRC)/include/linux/if_vlan.h $(KSRC)/net/8021q/vlan.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DVLAN_GRP_SET_DEV_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o "struct vlan_group" $(KSRC)/include/linux/if_vlan.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DVLAN_GRP_defined
endif

ifeq (,$(shell grep -o "vlan_hwaccel_receive_skb" $(KSRC)/include/linux/if_vlan.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DUSE_NEW_VLAN_MODEL
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o ndo_set_vf_mac $(KSRC)/include/linux/netdevice.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DNDO_VF_CFG_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o ndo_set_features $(KSRC)/include/linux/netdevice.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DNDO_SET_FEATURES_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -so "ethtool_cmd_speed_set" $(KSRC)/include/linux/ethtool.h \
                        $(KSRC)/include/uapi/linux/ethtool.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DETHTOOL_CMD_SPEED_SET_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -so "ethtool_cmd_speed" $(KSRC)/include/linux/ethtool.h \
                    $(KSRC)/include/uapi/linux/ethtool.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DETHTOOL_CMD_SPEED_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o "ethtool_phys_id_state" $(KSRC)/include/linux/ethtool.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DPHYS_ID_STATE_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o "flash_device" $(KSRC)/include/linux/ethtool.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DETHTOOL_FLASH_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o "get_sset_count" $(KSRC)/include/linux/ethtool.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DETHTOOL_SSET_COUNT_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o "set_dump" $(KSRC)/include/linux/ethtool.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DETHTOOL_SET_DUMP_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o "ethtool_ops_ext" $(KSRC)/include/linux/ethtool.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DETHTOOL_OPS_EXT_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o "pci_enable_pcie_error_reporting" $(KSRC)/include/linux/aer.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DAER_REPORTING_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o "pci_physfn" $(KSRC)/include/linux/pci.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DPCI_PHYSFN_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o "set_rxnfc" $(KSRC)/include/linux/ethtool.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DETHTOOL_RXNFC_OPS_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o ndo_get_stats64 $(KSRC)/include/linux/netdevice.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DNDO_GET_STATS64_defined
endif

ifneq (,$(shell grep -o txq_trans_update $(KSRC)/include/linux/netdevice.h))
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DTXQ_TRANS_UPDATE_defined
endif
# ************* End header checks *****************

# ************* Targets ***************************
ifeq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
ifeq ($(KDIR),)
    KDIR ?= /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build
endif   
default:
    @$(MAKE) -C$(KDIR) M=$$PWD
clean:
    @$(MAKE) -C$(KDIR) M=$$PWD clean
else
obj-$(CONFIG_BE2NET) += be2net.o
be2net-y :=  be_main.o be_cmds.o be_ethtool.o be_compat.o be_misc.o inet_lro.o
endif
# ************* End Targets ************************
```

I didn't see any $(CONFIG_BE2NET) variable declared prior to its usage, for instance.

Comment: `CONFIG_xxx` variables come from the `.config` file. You can't really hope to understand the Linux kernel makefiles without hours of reading, they're really hairy (and very different from typical makefiles).

Comment: Did you run `make KSRC=<source> KDIR=<build> config`?

Comment: Yeah I guess it's going to be a long week-end for me!

Comment: I tried `make KSRC=<source> KDIR=<build> config` but it just says there's no rule to build the target.

Comment: The if/else section is about building in the kernel tree versus outside. But what I don't see is how the module build rules in the Kernel's makefile system are supposed to figure out what to build simply from the `M=$$PWD`. In the in-kernel case, it spells out what object files are in the module.  It's possible that this is deduced from the pathname? I mean, that `$PWD` should be in a directory whose basename is be2net, and from that we know that there should be a `be2net-y` variable which lists the object files.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is you replace 
**obj-$(CONFIG_BE2NET) += be2net.o**
with 
**obj-m += be2net.o**

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir /usr/src <--This directory may already exists
cd usr/src
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.27.7.tar.gz 
tar -xvf linux-2.6.27.7.tar.gz 
ln -s /usr/src/linux-2.6.27.7 /usr/src/linux
cd /usr/src/linux
tar -xvf <nameofdriverdownload>.tar.gz <--If all goes well, this should inject the driver you downloaded into the kernel source 
make menuconfig <-- Select Desired options Here
make install
make modules_install
make initrd
```

I need to know the name of the driver and where you got it to make this answer exact.